# What are the absolute facial features which features sexual dimorphism in humans?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, reproduction, human-physiology, sexual-dimorphism

Apart from beard and moustache, is there any facial feature that would help to distinguish between men and women?

It is said that men have square, rectangular or oblong face and women have oval,diamond or heart shaped face.

Also men are said to have thicker eyebrows, widely spaced eyes and prominent eyebrow ridges while women have longer eyelashes.

Again, men have wider mouth and women have fuller lips.And men have sharp jawline while women have rounder jawline.

This list can be extended further. However, there are several exceptions to the above mentioned generalization.

So,how can we instinctively determine biological sex(male or female) of someone just by looking at the face?

Comment: If you want to know how the brain 'instinctively' decides male or female you can go to https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Roni Saiba How can I transfer this question to other StackExchange category? I want to know both about psychological aspect of recognizer and physiological characters of a person whose sex is to be recognized just by looking at facial features.

Comment: You can join the other stackexchange. I think moderators can transfer questions around so you can contact them in chat.